# sort a cell array according to another cell array

Tags: matlab

I have two cell arrays,

```
reference = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'H'}, {'D'}, {'G'}];
array2 = [{'A'}, {'G'}, {'H'}, {'B'}, {'D'}];
```

Is there any smart way in **matlab** to sort array2, with respect to the cell array reference;

The function should return indices for array2, in the same order as "reference" (array2 will be come identical to the reference).

for e.g

```
magic_order = function(array2, reference)
....
end
```

magic_order(array2, reference) will return

```
1,4,3,5,2
```

and now, if I do

```
array2(1,4,3,5,2)
```

I will get the same as the reference

**sort function**

```
reference = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'H'}, {'D'}, {'G'}];
array2 = [{'A'}, {'G'}, {'H'}, {'B'}, {'D'}];
[a, b] = sort(reference)
isequal(reference, array2(b))
ans = 0
```

Comment: Title says match, question says sort. Which is it?

Comment: sorry - I didn't expect, wording will make confusion. Basically the out come of whatever you suggest, makes(order) array2, identical to the reference.

Comment: That does not clarify. Please provide an example of the output(s) you are expecting. As stated, the obvious answer is `array2 = reference`

Comment: I updated the question; I am after the indices ... meaning how array2 should be reordered, in order to become the reference ! is it more clear now ?

Comment: I believe you want the 2nd output of MATLAB's [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html?searchHighlight=sort#description) function...

Comment: @excaza you are not trying to be helpful by being super impatient ! I am sure, after complaining so many times on the question and asking for clarification, still haven't read the question yet !

Comment: @user702846 as I've noted below, you need to start working on that patience yourself. You've just recently added crucial information to your question, before that it was completely unclear. Bear with those who make an effort to help you out, in their free time.

Comment: @user702846 I'm not sure why you're expecting people to put effort into reading your question when you can't put effort into stating it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second output of `ismember` could also be useful.

```
reference = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'H'}, {'D'}, {'G'}];
array2 = [{'A'}, {'G'}, {'H'}, {'B'}, {'D'}];
[~, pos] = ismember(reference,array2);
```

Result:

```
>> isequal(array2(pos),reference)

ans =

     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
reference = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'H'}, {'D'}, {'G'}];
array2 = [{'A'}, {'G'}, {'H'}, {'B'}, {'D'}];

[~, ~, idx] = intersect(reference, array2, 'stable');
```

Which returns:

```
>> isequal(reference, array2(idx))

ans =

     1
```

The first output of `intersect` (which I've ignored) using [`setOrder='stable'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html#inputarg_setOrder), returns the values common to both `reference` and `array2` in the same order as `reference`. The third output is the index of `array2` in this first output. Assuming the cell arrays are equal, this will be the index of `array2` in `reference`.